# “Was not having” vs. “did not have”

Tags: present-progressive

In a TV show there was a narration saying that “He recently lost his medical license for administering CPR to a person who as it turned out was not having a heart attack.”

Would it be weird if it was said “He recently lost his medical license for administering CPR to a person who as it turned out did not have a heart attack.”?

Comment: It would be weirder.

Comment: The sentence is ok.  CPR must be provided at the moment cardiac arrest is diagnosed, i.e. at the time the victim *is having* a  "heart attack", which, in this context, is being used as a synonym for cardiopulmonary arrest.